# Labelling layer not from attribute fields QGIS API v2.14?

Tags: labeling, qgis-2

How to label vector layer with my own values that aren't stored in the attribute fields?

Comment: is there any 'connection' between both?  Eg. a common ID?

Comment: In a side note: You should consider updating your QGIS, the current LTR is 3.4.

Comment: are you using the same label for all feature ? if not why not storing in the value in the attribute table ? Please provide more details in order to get meaningful answer

Comment: Same label for all features. I have temporary layer which I want to label with value got by another part of code and I want to avoid manipulations with attributes if it's possible. Is there a way to do it with layer.setCustomProperty() or something similar? Can't get QGIS v3 cause I forced to use RHEL.